# Date conversion in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I am importing data from CSV inside Rails 3.2 and saving it to mongodb collection and everything works fine except the date field. The imported date format is DD/MM/YYY. Please how can I convert the imported date to YYYY-MM-DD?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use date parsing like this:

```
Date.strptime('01/02/2003', '%d/%m/%Y').to_s    #=> "2003-02-01"
```

- [`Date.strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) creates a `Date` object from a string in the given format
- [`Date#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-to_s) returns it in the ISO 8601 format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD)

But it depends on how big your CSV is - this would create a bunch of intermediate `Date` objects which would be a bit slower than a (slightly ugly) string indexing approach:

```
def reformat_date(date)
  "#{date[6..9]}-#{date[3..4]}-#{date[0..1]}"
end

reformat_date('01/02/2003')     #=> "2003-02-01"
```

**Update**

I was curious so I ran some quick benchmarks - the date parsing method was about 2.7 times slower than the string method (5.289s vs 1.981s for a million conversions, Ruby 1.9.3/Windows). YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the benchmarks as well I will keep the alternative solution in mind as data volume ramps up

Answer (score 1):

You may need

```
require 'date'
```

Then use the following statement to parse the date:

```
d = Date.strptime('09/10/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Using the following examples will return the right format:

```
d.year #=> 2012
d.mon  #=> 10
d.day  #=> 9
d.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')  #=> "2012/10/09"
```

Then save it to the database. I'm not familiar with mongodb, though, but I'm sure you know what to do.

For more information on date parsing you should visit http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html.